# Sizing images of unknown size to a specific size without cropping. (Letterboxing)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to take an image from an external URL and put it in a specifically sized div.

For instance a div that is 300x200.  The image at the external URL could be landscape or portrait and I don't wan't to have the image cropped with something like `overflow:hidden`

Is there a good/clever way to do this?

Comment: Opera has a thing similar to what I want.  http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-object-fit-object-position/

Comment: Is javascript my only option?  And if so, does anyone have a good resource on someone who has already done it?

Comment: So you need to fit image in the `div` block with preserving aspect ratio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try 
    #your-div img {
        max-width: 100%
        max-height: 100%;
        }

this should do the job for you as in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/trickeedickee/xWeVK/

Comment: That won't constrain the height.